# VS Create Unit Tests command doesn't work for internal methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

Upon writing some unit tests, I decided to let Visual Studio's Create Unit Tests command generate some unit test stubs for me. I noticed, however, that if the class the `public` method lives in is `internal`, the Create Unit Tests command will not generate a stub, but instead spits out this message:

> Create Unit Tests is supported only within a public class or a public method.

I understand what the message is saying. However, I have set the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute inside of `AssemblyInfo.cs`, exposing my `internal` methods to my test assembly. I'm wondering - does Visual Studio's Create Unit Tests command have no knowledge of this setting? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Good chances are, VS tool has no knowledge of `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. The only way to fix this problem would be fixing the tool itself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight weeell, that's definitely not ideal. :\

Comment: The tool is different assembly which try to access your application method, which don't mentioned in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.

Comment: @Fabio so you're saying I should expose my internal methods to the tool's assembly?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `InternalsVisibleTo` in the first place.

Comment: @Fabio sorry, would you care to explain in more detail?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The workaround it to make your methods public.

The message is clean. I do think that only testing public methods is a good best practice so go for that. And I see "InternalsVisibleTo" as a temporary workaround when getting legacy code covered with test, it is not a permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I do see some benefit in testing private and/or internal methods.

Comment: I bet you do, but then you can use this tool for those methods.

Comment: I’m assuming you meant “can’t”?

Comment: you are right, and sorry for not being very polite in my comment. The way I see the relationship between production code and the unit test code base is just like another client (and that is what it is - another assembly using you API), and then it makes no sense having it calling internal methods. You want to test the code in the same way that it is used by real world clients.